# vuetify 'v-app' tag makes everything disappear

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to import vuetify on my vue app but my UI components are not looking correctly as shown here:

[image: textbox problem]

I read that this is caused when you are not using the v-app tag on the app.vue component.  However, when I try this, all the elements of the app disappear on the browser. I also get 3-5 console errors about not being able to recognize vuetify functions or calling functions from undefined variables.

app.vue:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <router-view>
    </router-view>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

main.js:

```
//imports
  import vue from 'vue';
  import vuetify from 'vuetify';

//bindings
  vue.use(vuetify);

//export
  new vue({
    vuetify,
    render: a => a(app),
  }).$mount('#app');
```

index.html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the css file.

In your main.js add `import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'`

More info: [Getting started](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start) for Vuetify 2.0

I think if you are just starting, using `vue add vuetify` would be easier if you do have @vue/cli 3.0 or above.

Comment: I tried all 3 of those and still nothing.  I know it has something to do with the v-app tag cause when i turn it on and off on a working sample, that same textbox error shown on the screenshot occurs.

Comment: @dizad87 Do you have `    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@latest/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">` in your html head?

Comment: yup exactly those 2 and no luck, do you have your sample to send so I can see why yours is working?

Comment: You can just start from scratch following the vuetify guide. That would be what I will do.

Comment: I thought about that but I'm already pretty far in with my app, it's full-stack with almost 10 pages and 20 dialogs and all the api connections setup and working properly, if i can get it to use vuetify it'd be a huge win for me, it has better components that boostrap and jquery ui in my opinion